# Combining two different ActiveRecord collections into one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I want create a visual timeline of all company events. The HTML for the timeline is built using a `loop`.

For simplicity let's assume two models `Hire` & `Deal`. Both models have a `date` attribute and some model specific attributes. How do I merge the `ActiveRecord` results of both models, and then `order` the combined hash by `date`, into a single hash that I can loop through?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, assuming that the result of querying both `Hire` and `Deal` models is an array of objects (*collection*), then you just use [`+`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-2B) to concatenate them into a new array and sort items by `date` with [`sort_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-sort):

```
combined = ( Hire.all + Deal.all ).sort_by(&:date)
```

or use [`concat`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-concat) to concatenate one collection with another:

```
combined = Hire.all.concat( Deal.all ).sort_by(&:date)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. The issue with this is that I would still need to sort the combined hash by `date` for the timelie to properly be displayed. Any suggestions how to achieve this?

Comment: Thanks a lot for this

Comment: One short question if you feel like it: Do you have a suggestion for how to distinguish records by Model?

Comment: It isn't a hash, it is an array, and it will be sorted by Date. You can iterate over the array and ask each object what their type is: `combined.each{|c| c.class.name}`

Comment: @Matthias you should also try the code out in Rails Console before asking follow up questions. That way you will have a better understanding of what is going on.

Comment: This approach isn't suitable in cases where you want to paginate the collection. To use pagination, the easiest solution would be to use the new [rails delegated types feature](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/DelegatedType.html).