# Rails 4 - Display content of two models in a single partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, methods, scope

I'm trying to figure out how to display the content from two separate models in a single view.

I have models for Profile, Jobs and Qualification. In the profile view, I want to show a single timeline of a profiles, jobs and qualifications, sorted in chronological order.

The closest example I can find from someone on SO is: [Rails: Combining two different ActiveRecord collections into one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36094710/rails-combining-two-different-activerecord-collections-into-one)

I'm getting stuck thinking about how to do this.

The model associations are:

Profile has_many :jobs, has_many :qualifications

Each of Jobs and Qualifications belong_to :profile

The Jobs table has:

```
t.integer  "profile_id"
t.string   "company"
t.date     "start_date"
t.date     "end_date"
t.string   "title"
t.text     "description"
t.boolean  "current_job"
t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
```

The qualifications table has:

```
t.string   "level"
t.string   "title"
t.string   "institution"
t.integer  "year_earned"
t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
t.integer  "profile_id"
t.boolean  "pending"
```

In my profile view, here is what I'm trying:

I don't want :created at to be the sort value, but I'm stuck thinking about where and how to define a function that determines whether a job is a current_job and if so, pins it to the top of the timeline and similarly, if a qualification is :pending, it is pinned at the top, after a current job (if any).

Then, each remaining job and qualification should be sorted chronologically by :end_date if it is a job or :year_earned if it is a qualification.

Then, they should be combined and displayed in a single view.

Here is my attempt at writing the methods:

In Job.rb

```
   class Job < ActiveRecord::Base


  # --------------- associations
  belongs_to :profile


  # --------------- scopes


  timeline_scope :previous_jobs order('end_date DESC')


  # --------------- class methods

  def period
    [self.start_date.strftime('%B %Y'), end_date.strftime('%B %Y')].compact.join(" - ")
  end

  def current_job?
    if self.curent_job == true
      [self.start_date.strftime('%B %Y'), '(continuing)'].join(', ')
    end  
  end

  def previous_jobs
    if self.curent_job == false
      self.period
    end  
  end
```

In the qualification model, I have:

```
    class Qualification < ActiveRecord::Base

  # --------------- associations
  belongs_to :profile

  #to do - add relationship with universities

  # --------------- scopes


  scope :pending, -> { where(pending: true) }
  scope :completed_award, ->{ order('year_earned DESC')}


  # --------------- class methods

  def completed_award
    if self.pending == false
      [title, institution, year_earned].join(', ')
    end  
  end

  def current_study
    [title, institution, year_earned, '(currently studying)'].join(', ')
  end


end
```

Im not sure that the above methods and scopes are correctly set out or not. I'm finding it difficult to learn how to do this well.

My next step is how to figure out how to say how to combine them in the right order, which is:

1. if there is a current job, that is first
2. if there is a pending qualification that is next
3. if there are prior jobs and qualifications they are merged and then listed in chronological order.

My thought is that the correct place to try to write this method is in the profile model.

This is my attempt (in profile.rb):

```
def timeline_list
    self.job.current_job?
    self.qualification.current_study.any?
    combined = self.job.previous_jobs.concat( Qualification.completed_award ).sort_by(&:timeline_date)
  end



    def timeline_date_historic
    if self.job (:end_date.strftime('%Y'))
    elsif self.qualification (:year_earned)
    end
  end

  def timeline_date_current
    self.job.current_job? && self.qualifiction.pending.any?
  end
```

My final step would then be to write in the profile show:

```
<% profile.combined = ( Profile.timeline_date_historic + Profile.timeline_date_current).each do |timeline| %>
```

Can anyone offer any help with how to code this? I have written these methods and scopes but I don't think any of it is correct.  The only thing I know is that its wrong, but I am stuck as to how to go about setting it up to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While combining two different scopes can cause issues when trying to access them. (E.g the column names will be changed from object to object)

You can do something like this

```
#app/models/job.rb
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :profile

  scope :current_jobs, -> {where(current_job: true)}
  scope :job_order, -> { order('end_date asc') }

end

#app/models/qualification.rb
class Qualification < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :profile

  scope :pending_qualifications, -> {where(pending: true)}
  scope :qualifications_order, -> { order('year_earned asc') }


end

#app/models/profile.rb
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :jobs
  has_many :profiles


  def self.time_line
    #joining the scops
    # you may change the order as you wish 
    Job.current_jobs +
    Qualification.pending_qualifications +
    Job.job_order +
    Qualification.qualifications_order
  end
end
```

and in your view, you can call it as

```
<%= Profile.time_line %>
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your needs, your algorithm could be like:

1. Find the profile
2. Get the current job and put it in a list `data = [profile.current_job]`.
3. Get pending qualifications and concatenate to the list. For example: `data = data.concat(profile.qualifications.pending)`.
4. Create another list and put all others qualifications and jobs, and order it by the fields you want to. [Array#sort](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-sort) method should help.
5. After all, concatenate the second list to the first.

Comment: Any idea how to do these steps